# Allow multiple roles to specific user

Tags: user-roles

I want create a plugin for when I edit some specific user from back end so I want an option to apply multiples roles for that user for some specific time period.

How can i apply multiple roles to specific user by programmatically.?

Comment: Instead of assigning multiple roles, assign and later remove capabilities to the existing (or newly created) role using `add_cap()` and `remove_cap()` functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Max.
But can i manage users role assign or Unassign functionality with crone?
How can i create this functionality with crone in wordpress?

Comment: When you need a piece of working code somebody write for you just hire somebody. The purpose of this site is experience exchange. When you've tried something (show the code) and stuck with it then [Search and research](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.